# Having trouble creating an App Script email system

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with my email system on google sheets, utilizing app script
My problems so far:

- My email subjects are with this kind of title: "<name>, 
   
   we are missing you" When it should have the name of the person i'm sending the message to and it ain't showing, not sure why
- The image i'm trying to use ain't being reduced to my desired width/height

I'll show you the code now and after, some images:

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows in which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

function sendEmail() {
// URL of the logo to be included in the email (Remember to use a logo in .png)
var logoUrl = "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E12AQHwckJ-hv-0rg/article-cover_image-shrink_600_2000/0/1632191739115?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=CbEz6-6qwHRuHy65RGXc2BOzy7Fix_eRlh_3dZFut2Q";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the email addresses
var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getDataRange();

// Retrieve the subject and message of the email from specific sheets (A2/A4)
var subjectTemplate = ss.getSheetByName("email").getRange("A2").getValue();
var message = ss.getSheetByName("email").getRange("A4").getValue();

// Get values for each row in the specified range
var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (var i = 1; i \< data.length; ++i) {
var row = data\[i\];
var name = row\[0\]; // First column of the "cadastros" sheet (Name)
var emailDestination = row\[1\]; // Second column of the sheet (Email)
var emailSent = row\[2\]; // Third Column of the sheet ()

    // If the email is empty, break out of the loop
    if (emailDestination == "") {
      break;
    }
    
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicate emails for those already marked as EMAIL_SENT
      // Customize the subject including the person's name
      var subject = subjectTemplate.replace("<nome>", name);
      
      var message2 = message.replace("<nome>", name); // Replaces the <nome> placeholder with the name from the sheet
      
      // Send Alert Email
      sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message2, logoUrl); // The email is sent along with the logo (logoUrl)
      ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getRange(1 + i , 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // The column with status (emailsent) is marked as EMAIL_SENT, avoiding duplicates
      Logger.log("Email sent to "+ emailDestination +" successfully!") // Logged in console that the email was sent successfully
      // Ensure that the cell is updated immediately in case the script is interrupted (Avoid problems)
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("No new email to send!")
    }

}
}

// Function to send an email with a resized logo
function sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message, logoUrl) {
// Fetch the Blob of the logo
var logoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logoUrl).getBlob().setName("logoBlob");

// In case of an error with the logoUrl
if (logoUrl) {
var logoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logoUrl).getBlob().setName("logoBlob");
} else {
Logger.log("The logo URL is not defined.");
}

// Send the email
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emailDestination,
subject: subject,
htmlBody: message + "<br><br><img src="cid:logo">",
inlineImages: {
logo: logoBlob,
}
});
}
```

[[email config sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P3vI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0hfs.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFLkt.png)

I tried all different types of things, but i'm not sure what's wrong with the code
I'd be eternally grateful if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it this way:

```
function unknown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("cadastros");
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName("email");
  var message = esh.getRange("A4").getValue();

  for (var i = 1; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var row = vs[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var emailDestination = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailDestination && emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subjectTemplate = esh.getRange("A2").getValue();//I moved this into the loop so that the template would start fresh for every loop
      var subject = subjectTemplate.replace("<nome>", name);
      var message2 = message.replace("<nome>", name); // Replaces the <nome> placeholder with the name from the sheet
      sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message2, logoUrl); // The email is sent along with the logo (logoUrl)
      ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getRange(1 + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // The column with status (emailsent) is marked as EMAIL_SENT, avoiding duplicates
      Logger.log("Email sent to " + emailDestination + " successfully!") // Logged in console that the email was sent successfully
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("No new email to send!")
    }
  }
}
```

You could also do it this way:

```
function unknown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("cadastros");
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName("email");
  var message = esh.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var t = esh.getRange("A2").getValue();
  for (var i = 1; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var row = vs[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var emailDestination = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailDestination && emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subjectTemplate = t;//reinitialize the template before every replace
      var subject = subjectTemplate.replace("<nome>", name);
      var message2 = message.replace("<nome>", name); // Replaces the <nome> placeholder with the name from the sheet
      sendEmailWithLogo(emailDestination, subject, message2, logoUrl); // The email is sent along with the logo (logoUrl)
      ss.getSheetByName("cadastros").getRange(1 + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // The column with status (emailsent) is marked as EMAIL_SENT, avoiding duplicates
      Logger.log("Email sent to " + emailDestination + " successfully!") // Logged in console that the email was sent successfully
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("No new email to send!")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, you really helped me, Cooper~